# sed replace multiple xml tag

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I need to replace multiple lines in xml file using sed. here is my input file:

```
<firstTag>Y</firstTag>
<secondTag/>
```

I want to replace those line into below format:

```
<firstTag></firstTag>
<secondTag>Y</secondTag>
```

I tried using this command:

```
sed -i -r "s#<firstTag>Y</firstTag>\n.*#<firstTag></firstTag>\n<secondTag>Y</secondTag>#g" input.txt
```

But it is not working. I also notice there are some tab (^I using less command) before the secondTag. Will it affect the sed command? Please help me about this.

Update: There are multiple occurance of secondTag in the file and I only want to change the secondTag value to Y only after it find that previous value of firstTag is Y. For example, if in input.txt:

```
<firstTag>Y</firstTag>
<secondTag/>
<firstTag/>
<secondTag/>
```

I want it to be replaced into:

```
<firstTag></firstTag>
<secondTag>Y</secondTag>
<firstTag/>
<secondTag/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -r '/<firstTag>.*<\/firstTag>/{N;s#(<firstTag>)(.*)((</firstTag>\n)<secondTag/>)#\1\4<secondTag>\2</secondTag>#g}' file.txt
```

Comment: This gives wrong `<secondTag/>` correct request is `</secondTag>`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;s|^(<firstTag>)Y(</firstTag>\n<(secondTag))/>$|\1\2>Y</\3>|;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk -F"[<>/]" '/^<firstTag>/ {f=$3;$0="<"$2"></"$2">"} /^<secondTag\/>/ {$0="<"$2">" f "</"$2">"}1' file
<firstTag><firstTag/>
<secondTag>Y</secondTag>
```

Regarding this comment:

> sorry, I forgot to mention that there are multiple occurance of
>   secondTag and I only want to change the secondTag value to Y only
>   after it find that previous value of firstTag is Y

Here is another `awk` that only change the first `secondTag` if there is a `firstTag`, ignore all other:

```
cat file
<secondTag/>
<firstTag>Y</firstTag>
<secondTag/>
<someOtherTag>
<secondTag/>
```

The `awk`

```
awk -F"[<>/]" '/^<firstTag>/ {f=$3;$0="<"$2"></"$2">"} f && /^<secondTag\/>/ {$0="<"$2">" f "</"$2">";f=""}1' file
<secondTag/>
<firstTag></firstTag>
<secondTag>Y</secondTag>
<someOtherTag>
<secondTag/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about seperating the two tag replacements?

```
sed -i -r -e "s#<firstTag>Y</firstTag>#<firstTag></firstTag>#" -e "s#<secondTag/>#<secondTag>Y</secondTag>#" input.txt
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that there are multiple occurance of secondTag and I only want to change the secondTag value to Y only after it find that previous value of firstTag is Y.